# CNAMES, hostfiles and PowerShell Remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Has anybody gotten powershell remoting to work against CNAMES or host files.

a way to test, create a PSsession against localhost to make sure its working fine... then have a host record to 127.0.0.1 called something, then try to create a pssession against that.

I get this sort of error

```
[funkymonkey] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot pr
ocess the request. The following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: The network pat
h was not found.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two d
omains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configu
ration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. F
or more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PS
   RemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Comment: Are you using Kerberos authentication?

Comment: obviously i must be, i thought i was using NTLM in my intranet zone.

Comment: Ignore that. I get the same error on my NTLM system. Working on that now.

Comment: I am sure this has to do something with WSMAN settings. Not just able to figure out. BTW, by using -Credential, I get an access denied error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If NTLM isn't working, I think you're getting hit by the loopback check stuff added in winsrv 2003 sp1+. You can add the CNAMEs to a special registry key that will include them in the exception list (which already includes localhost.)

ps> new-itemproperty hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\control\Lsa\MSV1_0
BackConnectionHostNames `
       -propertyType multistring -val "cname1","cname1.local"

Some people just turn it off entirely (the loopback check) by setting a dword DisableLoopbackCheck (google it) but you really should control it tighter with the former method instead of taking the lazy route.

IIRC, this security feature prevents a particular type of credential theft called a "reflection attack." I don't remember the methodology but i'm sure you could find it online.